# Shared scope between middleware and consumer

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, masstransit

**Goal**: *Read message headers and place them in a scoped dependency (IHeaderData, it's typed data) that will be available for all consumers requiring IHeaderData (constructor injected).*

So far I've only been able to "store" my data using payloads. But that would require some footwork for consumers and I would like them to just ask for it (if they need it).

I've been trying to create a new scope in the middleware and then set the headerdata to an object retrieved in that scope. But I still seem to get a new scope when requiring IHeaderData in the consumer.

**Edit**:
A bit of progress here. By getting the IServiceScope from payload I can now get the headerdata which will be available in the consumer (constructor injected).

```
public async Task Send(TContext ctx, IPipe<TContext> next)
{
    if (ctx is ConsumeContext consumeContext && consumeContext.TryGetPayload(out IServiceScope scope))
    {
        var headerData = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IHeaderData>();

        headerData.Data1 = consumeContext.Headers.Get<string>("x-data1)";
    }

    await next.Send(context);
}
```

I'm trying to find some documentation on payloads. I don't really understand how it works. How come IServiceScope is in payloads suddently?

Comment: Please include code snippets of what you have tried. This purpose of this site is for people to help you solve things blocking your own problem solving, not to solve problems for you wholesale.

Comment: What do you mean with "store your data using payloads"?What type of data is that?  Some collection tied to a request, thats unique to the request?`HttpContext.Features` may be more suitable for you, defining an `IHeaderFeature` interface and class and add it to `HttpContext.Features`. It will be available for the duration of the request to anywhere where HttpContext is accessible, then you can have a simple service that injects `IHttpContextAccessor` and access and returns the data. If its http headers you need, just do the same but w/o `HttpContext.Features` (request headers alreadyavailable)